# how to simplify if statement yes

Tags: python

What's the best way to simplify this if?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ans=input("choose yes or no: ")

if ans == "yes" or ans == "YES" or ans == "y" or ans == "Y":
    print("ok")
else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: Do you want yEs or yeS? If so, check [.lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) aswell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could check it with list:

```
if ans in ['yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y']:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend streamlining it as follows:

```
if ans.lower().startswith('y'):
    print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

If lowercasing the whole thing when we're only interested in the first character feels wasteful, you can slice the first character (slices don't fail with `IndexError`s like ordinary indexing can):

```
if ans[:1].lower() == 'y':
```

Comment: will also catch 'yNo' as yes... but that's probably not a big deal...

Comment: But it will also catch, say, "yse" as "yes." I'm happy with the tradeoff.

Comment: Yeah and this would have been my solution as well, just wanted to point this out...

Answer (score 2):

Make a `set` of your acceptable answers. This will also give you a lookup time of `O(1)` which may come in handy once you have a large number of acceptable answers.

```
acceptable_answers = {'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y'}
if ans in acceptable_answers:
     #do stuff
else:
     #do other stuff
```

Comment: what is "set" keywork?

Comment: @PolHallen a `set` is an unordered collection of unique elements.

Comment: You can use a literal if you want, e.g. `...= {'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y'}`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I like it

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

```
accepted = answer.lower() in ['y','yes']
print ('ok' if accepted else 'no')
```